# Code Transformation from Java to Go

Tags: go

I don't know syntax of Go. Can anybody help me to convert following java code in google's go language .

```
import java.io.*;

class FileWrite 
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    try {
      // Create file 
      FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
      out.write("Hello Java");
      // Close the output stream
      out.close();
    } catch (Exception e){ //Catch exception if any
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

This java code creates a file named out.txt and write a string (Hello Java) on the file.

Comment: What have you got so far? Is there a particular difficulty with the syntax that you're having?

Comment: I don't understanding, how to create a file in go and how to write on it. Sorry, for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, how this problem can solved ? [play.golang.org/p/169zmQvK7m](http://play.golang.org/p/169zmQvK7m) –
>   alessandro

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func routine(fd *os.File) {
    abc := 1
    fd.WriteString("Hello Go " + strconv.Itoa(abc) + " ok\n")
    fd.WriteString("\nHello Gopher!\n")
}

func main() {
    fd, err := os.Create("out.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer fd.Close()
    abc := 1
    fd.WriteString("Hello Go " + strconv.Itoa(abc) + " ok\n")
    fd.WriteString("\nHello Gopher!\n")
    routine(fd)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fd, err := os.Create("out.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    // defer calls a function at the end of the current function.           
    defer fd.Close()

    fd.WriteString("Hello Gopher!\n")
}
```

I hope this helps. If this is not clear, please specify which part needs explanation.

Comment: This is nice. I add abc := 1 (integer declaration) and fd.WriteString("Hello Gopher!" , abc " ok\n"). Go can't print int together with string ? How can it possible ?

Comment: Why wtr.WriteString("Hello Gopher!\n") takes it to new line ?

Answer (score 3):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("out.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    wtr := bufio.NewWriter(f)
    abc := 1
    _, err = wtr.WriteString("Hello Go " + strconv.Itoa(abc) + " ok\n")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    err = wtr.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}

file out.txt:
Hello Go 1 ok\n
```

> [String literals](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#String_literals)
>
> A string literal represents a string constant obtained from
>   concatenating a sequence of characters. There are two forms: raw
>   string literals and interpreted string literals.
>
> Raw string literals are character sequences between back quotes ``.
>   Within the quotes, any character is legal except back quote. The value
>   of a raw string literal is the string composed of the uninterpreted
>   characters between the quotes; in particular, backslashes have no
>   special meaning and the string may span multiple lines.
>
> Interpreted string literals are character sequences between double
>   quotes "". The text between the quotes, which may not span multiple
>   lines, forms the value of the literal, with backslash escapes
>   interpreted as they are in character literals (except that \' is
>   illegal and \" is legal). The three-digit octal (\nnn) and two-digit
>   hexadecimal (\xnn) escapes represent individual bytes of the resulting
>   string; all other escapes represent the (possibly multi-byte) UTF-8
>   encoding of individual characters. Thus inside a string literal \377
>   and \xFF represent a single byte of value 0xFF=255, while ÿ, \u00FF,
>   \U000000FF and \xc3\xbf represent the two bytes 0xc3 0xbf of the UTF-8
>   encoding of character U+00FF.

Comment: Your "translation" is more accurate, mine is a free-form one!

Comment: This is nice. I add abc := 1 (integer declaration) and wtr.WriteString("Hello Go" , abc, " ok\n"). Go can't print int together with string ? How can it possible ?

Comment: Why wtr.WriteString("Hello Go\n") takes it to new line ?

Comment: `"Hello Go\n"` is an interpreted string literal therefore "\n" is interpreted as a newline character.